# Playlists in mediaplayers not able to trace song files after restarting ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: vlc, rhythmbox, music, audacious

Rhythmbox, VLC player, Audacious, I tried all. Similar problem arises. After creating playlists, it is working fine for the first time. After restarting and playing the playlists, error message appears telling that 'cannot find file.' The songs were saved in the system by windows7. Machine is double boot with Ubuntu and Windows7. Is it something connected with partitions?

Comment: Is the partition where your music is stored mounted in your ubuntu session?

Comment: I don't know anything about mounting. What is the procedure to mount it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question. I understand that the songs are in partition meant for `Windows`. Please check whether the `Windows` partition is listed in mounted partitions using the command:

```
df -h
```

In the case of `ubuntu 14.04`, by default user needs to enter sudo password to mount windows partition.

Or else you can add an entry in `/etc/fstab` at the end of the file.

[image]

See my above image of `Disk Utility` for example. Here songs are in partition `dev/sda5` (See the `Device` type in image) and the partion is `NTFS` (see `Type` in image). I have created a directory `mp3` in `/opt` to mount the partition.

Enter the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add the below entry as last line and save the file.

`/dev/sda5   /opt/mp3       ntfs    defaults        0       0`

You have to change `/dev/sda5` to your requirement. After reboot the partition will mount, by default. You don't need to mount the partition each time by using `sudo` password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Disk utility is installed in my system. How to run it?

Comment: Press `windows` key and type 'disk utility'.  You will be able to find the application.

Comment: My relevant drive is /dev/sda3. It contains files other than mp3. Is there any change in the command then?

Comment: You can create directory by any name not only `mp3`. In my example `sda5 `, becomes `/dev/sda3` in your case.